# Skip the whole row, If a cell is Null in MySQL table using PHP foreach

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
$cast_name_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["cast_name"]);
$cast_profile_path = explode(',',$result[$x]["cast_profile_path"]);
$cast_character = explode(',',$result[$x]["cast_character"]);

foreach( $cast_name_list as $index => $cast_name ) 
{
echo 'name = '.$cast_name.'<br/> ';
echo ' character name = '.$cast_character[$index].' <br/>';
echo ' profile path = '.$cast_profile_path[$index].' <br/><br/><br/>';
}
```

This is, how my data in MySQL table looks like:

```
cast_name       cast_character    cast_profile_path
Robert             Iron man       example.com/sdfsd.jpg
Rahul               Mohit         example.com/aadfsd.jpg
Tom                 Josh             Null
Tripp               James        example.com/zzz.jpg
```

What  I want:, If there is a `NULL` cell in the table, then the whole row will not echo.

i.e: `Tom                 Josh             Null`

**But, this is what my code echo**

```
name = robert
character name = Iron Man
profile path = example.com/sdfsd.jpg

name = Rahul
character name = Mohit
profile path = example.com/aadfsd.jpg


name = Tom
character name = Josh
profile path = example.com/zzz.jpg


name = Tripp
character name = James
profile path = Notice: Undefined offset: 8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
name = robert
character name = Iron Man
profile path = example.com/sdfsd.jpg

name = Rahul
character name = Mohit
profile path = example.com/aadfsd.jpg


name = Tripp
character name = James
profile path = Notice: example.com/zzz.jpg
```

Edit: Since one value is `null` in 3rd row, so `$cast_profile_path` array will contain only 4 values, while `$cast_name` & `$cast_character` contain 5 values.

Comment: You likely could just alter your `WHERE` clause to remove `NULL` by using `WHERE cast_profile_path != NULL` or what-have-you. May as well not pull the empty rows in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($cast_name_list as $index => $cast_name) {
    if (!array_key_exists($index, $cast_profile_path)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo 'name = '.$cast_name.'<br/> ';
    echo ' character name = '.$cast_character[$index].' <br/>';
    echo ' profile path = '.$cast_profile_path[$index].' <br/><br/><br/>';
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

**Note** Not sure if I understand correctly, do you store values separated by comma in table columns?